# Программа не видит validation.properties

Tags: java, spring

Вместо того что бы выводилось значение свойства, выводится просто текст, который я вписываю. Я пытался обойти эту проблему, вписывая значение ошибки напрямую (без properties файла), но после этого значения еще указывается имя переменной, к которой крепится ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return User.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    User user = (User) o;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "login", "NotEmpty");
    if (user.getLogin().length() < 6 || user.getLogin().length() > 32) {
        errors.rejectValue("login", "Size.userForm.login");
    }
    if (userService.findByUsername(user.getLogin()) != null) {
        errors.rejectValue("login", "Duplicate.userForm.login");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", 
"NotEmpty");
    if (user.getPassword().length() < 8 || user.getPassword().length() > 32) 
{
        errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
    }

    if (!user.getPasswordConfirm().equals(user.getPassword())) {
        errors.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", 
"Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm");

    }
}
}
```

application.properties:

```
NotEmpty=This field is required.
Size.userForm.login=Please use between 6 and 32 characters.
Duplicate.userForm.login=Someone already has that username.
Size.userForm.password=Try one with at least 8 characters.
Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm=These passwords don't match.
```

jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>
    <spring:bind path="login">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="text" path="login" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Login"
                        autofocus="true"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="login"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="password">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Password"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="passwordConfirm">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form- 
control"
                        placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="passwordConfirm"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

файл application.properties должен находиться \src\main\resources\application.properties